# python script to collect the hostname of remote windows server

Tags: python-2.7, wmi

I have python 2.7 installed on my windows 7 machine.I wrote a script to connect to the remote windows server and it worked fine. Now i want to execute a command on the remote server and collect the hostname.
I know how to collect local machine details but how to collect remote machine info??
Any help would be really appreciated.
here's the script

c = wmi.WMI(self.ip, user=self.username, password=self.password)

Answer (score 0):

Getting OS_Info from remote machine:

import wmi

"" "hostname=remote server ip or domain name"""

conn=wmi.WMI(hostname,user=username,password=password)

for os in conn.Win32_OperatingSystem():

```
  print os
```

Note:Make sure that your machine is connected to server domain or workgroup

[below links are the best tutorial for WMI]

< http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html>

http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.in/2008/12/python-monitor-windows-remotely-with.html